# Adding values among text in an Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet with 7895 lines, 6 columns in column B I have values like:

```
Classification 124: Item 1 (€2345,70) item 2 (€123) item 3 (€1456,75)
```

What I am trying to do is create a formula or function that sums 2345,70+123+1456,75.

I found something like this:

```
Function SumNums(rngS As Range, Optional strDelim As String = " ") As Double
    Dim vNums As Variant, lngNum As Long
    vNums = Split(rngS, strDelim)
    For lngNum = LBound(vNums) To UBound(vNums) Step 1
        SumNums = SumNums + Val(vNums(lngNum))
    Next lngNum
End Function
```

I tried to use this routine, but it’s not working in my specific case. I have to find a way that the numbers added are the ones like (€2345,70) with the parenthesis and the Euro sign.
But again, the numbers have an Euro sign but they are not formatted as currency.

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Function SumNums(rngS As Range, Optional strDelim As String = " ") As Double
    Dim vNums As Variant, lngNum As Long
    vNums = Split(rngS, strDelim)
    For lngNum = LBound(vNums) To UBound(vNums) Step 1
        SumNums = SumNums + Val(vNums(lngNum))
    Next lngNum
End Function

Ii does not work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information. Code is unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula (Add this to a Module in the VBA Editor - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>)

```
Function SumAllCurrencies(CellsToSum)
    Dim regexPattern: regexPattern = "€(\d*),?(\d*)?"
    Dim objRegex: Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = regexPattern
    End With
    Dim regexMatches: Set regexMatches = objRegex.Execute(CellsToSum.Value)
    Dim regexMatch
    
    Dim sumValue: sumValue = 0
    For Each regexMatch In regexMatches
        sumValue = sumValue + regexMatch.SubMatches.Item(0)
        If (IsNumeric(regexMatch.SubMatches.Item(1))) Then
            sumValue = sumValue + (regexMatch.SubMatches.Item(1) / 100)
        End If
    Next
        
    SumAllCurrencies = sumValue
    
    Set regexMatch = Nothing
    Set objRegex = Nothing
    Set regexMatches = Nothing
End Function
```

Then simply call it with `=SumAllCurrencies(A1)`

[image]

This works by regexing out any digits after a € sign, and any optional digits after a comma. It then adds together all the numbers direct after the € sign, and adds the numbers after the comma, divided by 100 (to treat them as cents instead of Euros.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was unbelievably fast and it works!
It helps, it helps a lot!
Thanks a lot.